# Updating records in sql server using textbox in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am having a hard time in updating the record in my database record. I assigned the values to textboxes from the sqlserver by having this code in Page_Load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string pn = (string)Session["prodname"];

SqlConnection camConnection = new SqlConnection();
private string s;
    s = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["polaroidConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    camConnection = new SqlConnection(s);

    SqlCommand select = new SqlCommand("Select * From productInfo Where ProductName= '" + pn + "'", camConnection);
    SqlDataReader camread;
    camConnection.Open();
    camread = select.ExecuteReader();
    while (camread.Read())
    {
        cat2.Text = camread[0].ToString();
        id2.Text = camread[1].ToString();
        pn2.Text = camread[2].ToString();
        desc2.Text = camread[3].ToString();
        price2.Text = camread[5].ToString();
    }

    camread.Close();
    camConnection.Close();

}
```

When I run the program, the records display in the textboxes. Then, I inserted codes in Button1_Click so that when I change the value of the textboxes, the changes will be sved in the database. Here is my code for Button1_Click.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    camConnection = new SqlConnection();
    private string s;
    s =     WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["polaroidConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    camConnection = new SqlConnection(s);

    camConnection.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("update productInfo set ProductName= '" + pn2.Text + "', Description='" + Convert.ToString(desc2.Text) + "' where ID='" + Convert.ToString(id2.Text) + "' ", camConnection);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    camConnection.Close();
}
```

But it seems that the system does not recognize the changes I made to the value of textbox. Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Can you show us the html code where these textboxes are defined?

Comment: Is change reflected in the database ?

Comment: @Kumar the records in the database are still the same.

Comment: Not sure what additem is, that might need converting.  Are you getting any errors?  Also the way you are concatenating strings to create your SQL is open to SQL injection attacks (https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). You would to better to use parameterised stored procedures or Entity Framework for database access.

Comment: this is general bad practice for web development. Storing business data in the session (this can be accessd or overriden by other users since it's a global session object). Use SQL Parameters (SQL Injections) and abstract UI from business logic with layers... to much to do =)